# Mass-renaming Git authors?

Tags: git

I'm using `svn2git` to create a Git repository from an existing SVN repository. I got it all downloaded (all 10+ branches, 10+ tags, >4000 commits) and in a Git repo. Now, unfortunately, all the authors are messed up.

All of the authors don't have email addresses or names, and most authors have used multiple email addresses over the life of the project, so I might like to merge them down. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5):

The tool you want is [`git-filter-branch`](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-filter-branch.html). This allows you to set up a "commit filter" that changes the author names for each commit in your repository.

This is a step that you would set up and run *once* after running `svn2git`. It's not something you would normally want to run on a Git repository that you've made any further commits to.

Your question indicates that "All of the authors don't have email addresses or names", which seems to indicate that something in `svn2git` didn't quite do what it was supposed to. However, note that Git has *two* names for each commit - the "author" and the "committer" (because they can be different).

Comment: svn doesn't (have to) have emails for user ids. It might just be a login.

Comment: That's true. I would still say that's a "name", just not a full name.

Comment: Could you link me to a "for instance" on what I'd need to do? I've got about 10-15 users over the lifetime of this project and I'd like to rename each of them; both their names and their email addresses.

Answer (score 4):

The tool you really want is [reposurgeon](http://www.catb.org/esr/reposurgeon/).

Once you get to your problem size (10s of authors, 1000s of commits) `git filter-branch` is just too slow and clunky. It only changes one author at a time while iterating over the entire repo and the entire process could take hours. I had 72 authors and 21000 commits which would have taken 18 hours!

While reposurgeon can be quite daunting at first, it is dead simple for this task.

1. Create an author mapping file (say `authors.txt`) similar to that required by `svn2git` anyway, containing one line per SVN author of the form

   `oldauthor = New Author <new@email>`

   Here you can map multiple SVN authors to one actual author if you like.
2. Go into your converted git repository and do

   `reposurgeon "verbose 1" "read" "authors read <../authors.txt" "write >../export"`
3. You now have a fast export file in the top-level directory. Convert this back to an actual repository as follows:

`mkdir ../new-repo && cd ../new-repo
    git init
    git fast-import < ../export
    git reset --hard HEAD   # I needed this step for some reason`

The whole procedure takes less than 2 minutes on my large repository and also leaves the original git repository intact - useful in case something goes wrong. And this is just the tip of the iceberg that is reposurgeon... Thanks, Eric!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using `git filter-branch` as suggested in previous answer:

```
git filter-branch --commit-filter '
    if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME" = "old.address@domain.tld" ];
    then
        GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="New Name" \
        GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="new.address@domain.tld" \
        GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="New Name" \
        GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="new.address@domain.tld" \
        git commit-tree "$@";
    else
        git commit-tree "$@";
    fi' -f HEAD
```

Rewrites all commits whom author is `old.address@domain.tld` to `New Name <new.address@domain.tld>`.